# Is it possible to use Spring to create a console application?

Tags: java, spring, console-application

Currently researching this topic. Is it possible to use the benefits of Spring to form a Console application? I mean, with scopes, autowiring and etc(found a bunch of examples of a basic "Set the context, init and go", but nothing more)?

Can't find any tutorials or helpful information on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are links to the Spring docs:
[3. Developing Spring Shell Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/dev-shell.html)
[4. Simple sample application using the Spring Shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/simple-application.html)

Comment: Thanks. Was looking by the word of "console" and struck only into basic tutorials.

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 6):

`CommandLineRunner` example. If you run this Spring Boot, the run method will be the entry point.

```
package com.mkyong;

import com.mkyong.service.HelloMessageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import static java.lang.System.exit;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private HelloMessageService helloService;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //disabled banner, don't want to see the spring logo
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);

    }

    // Put your logic here.
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(helloService.getMessage(args[0].toString()));
        } else {
            System.out.println(helloService.getMessage());
        }

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

[Details](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-non-web-application-example/)

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use Dropwizard framework, it provides so many required librairies in-build & can setup project within few minutes. Refer below link to know more about the dropwizard framework:
http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.0/docs/

Also you can get the sample project of dropwizard framework at below link:
https://github.com/lawakush9292/DropwizardProject

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try.

Comment: Yes just go through the documents linke shared in the answer and you can get idea about the framework.

Comment: They changed the documentation structure, but copy paste the names I wrote into google and it should take you there

Answer (score 1):

Spring is a framework which offers the dependency injection mechanism. It also supports segregation of service layer, web layer, and business layer but I believe that this is not what you want.

So the answer is **yes**. You can utilize the dependency injection service that provides in order to create a console application without facing any problems. Of course, the MVC model that offers is actually useless for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is what i wanted to know. First time applying Spring as a non-Web application.